# Mapping data frames with different dimensions in R

Tags: r, filter, mapping

I have two data frames.

The first one has a single column and 1000 rows. The values included this data frame belong to the interval (0,1].

The second data frame has 3 columns, and 5 number of rows of the following form:

```
From  To      Category
0.0   0.2        1
0.2   0.4        2
0.4   0.6        3
0.6   0.8        4
0.8   1.0        5
```

I am trying to assign/map the `Category` values to the values of the first data frame through the following R code:

```
for (i in (1:nrow(DataFrame1))){
  for (j in (1:(nrow(DataFrame2)))){
    if ( (DataFrame1$V1[i]>DataFrame2$From[j]) & (DataFrame1$V1[i]<=DataFrame2$To[j]) ){
      Result[i]<-DataFrame2$Category[j]
    }
  }
}
```

This code works correctly although for more number of rows it takes a lot of time. Is there a shortcut for this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `findInterval` function does this job nicely.

```
set.seed(1)
df1 <- data.frame(val = runif(10))
df1$Category <- findInterval(df1$val, vec = c(0,0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8), left.open = TRUE)
df1

#           val Category
# 1  0.26550866        2
# 2  0.37212390        2
# 3  0.57285336        3
# 4  0.90820779        5
# 5  0.20168193        2
# 6  0.89838968        5
# 7  0.94467527        5
# 8  0.66079779        4
# 9  0.62911404        4
# 10 0.06178627        1
```

Comment: In your example  `left.open = FALSE` correct? Shouldn't it be `TRUE`?

Comment: You are right, @Whitebeard13. I have edited my answer.

Comment: One question: Is it possible have `left.open=FALSE` only for the first observation of `V1` and `left.open=TRUE` for the rest of the cases?

Comment: You can actually hack it by setting 0 to, say, -0.01 :)